# Spring data Neo4j with JSF Java application

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I would like to use Spring Data Neo4j but I want use only this part of Spring. All my web application I want to build with JSF framework. I have problems to mix Spring Data Neo4j and JSF. Is it possible or is is worth to use spring data Neo4j instead of OGM Neo4j? Maybe is better to stay with simple OGM driver in my case?

Comment: Maybe would it be optimal to resign from advantages of Spring Data Neo4j and stay with clean JavaEE enviroment?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? There's no actual question here, just statements.

Comment: Thanks, it's clearer what you're asking now.